# JQuery ajax call to cross-domain webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I would like consume cross-domain web-service from client with jquery

```
function TestService() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://service.asmx/GetGeoCompletionList",
        data: { "prefixText":"eka", "count":"10", "contextKey":"Trace_0$Rus" },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

At the error hander I have:
textStatus=`parseerror`

XMLHttpRequest has status `200` and readyState `4`

errorThrown is `jQuery16103495572647140...78197139 was not called`

I've spent on it for a lot of hours and couldn't make it work. Can u help me?

**UPDATED**

Thanks, I change to GET, and fix my data string.

Service returns valid JSON object. I can see it at firebug on other site, which consume this service. But that site is getting common json(since it has one domain).

So, if the web-service returns valid JSON(not jsonp), I can't use the same method with jsonp? What can I do for consiming json web-service from other domain?

Comment: What does the HTTP request and HTTP response look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [parsererror after jQuery.ajax request with jsonp content type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359224/parsererror-after-jquery-ajax-request-with-jsonp-content-type)

Comment: If you don't understand why you can't consume the service if it just returns JSON instead of JSONP, read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp/2067584#2067584

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of problems:

1. Make sure you're using valid JSON
   as @Quentin mentioned.
2. Make sure you're using GET requests, as
   @lonesomeday mentioned
3. Make sure the response from the server is
   JSONP, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359224/parsererror-after-jquery-ajax-request-with-jsonp-content-type)

Answer (score 3):

That string you are passing and claiming is JSON isn't JSON.

Only `"` characters may be used to quote strings.

Also, you can't make a cross domain JSON-P POST request.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do cross-domain POST requests using JSONP. JSONP works by adding `script` tags to the page.  `script` tags always fetch their source using GET HTTP requests.  You won't get any data posted.