# ExtJS jsonp access cross domain cgi file but respond syntaxError

Tags: javascript, extjs, jsonp, extjs5, extjs-mvc

I define a store in my extjs5 MVC project. I want to access cross domain cgi file so set proxy type: 'jsonp'.

After I load the store the Chrome show me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Here is my store:

```
Ext.define('Myproject.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Myproject.model.MyStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://mylink:8000/setting.cgi',
        extraParams: {
            act: 'get_lib_list'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

Response content:

```
{ "success": false, "error_code": 5006, "error_msg": "No such file or directory (-2)" }
```

How do I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597295/json-parsing-issue-between-sencha-touch-and-wordpress-buddypress-api/14597941#14597941

Comment: Hi Evan. Thanks for your reply. So the server should wrap the data via the passing callback function right?