# How to consume web services in Sencha Touch 2.2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, jsonp, extjs-mvc, sencha-architect

am new to Sencha Touch. I tried to consume web service but its keeps saying "Unable to load data using the supplied configuration.Open in Browser". My store is

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyJsonPStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.MyModel'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
        storeId: 'MyJsonPStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'errors'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and my model is

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'message'
            },
            {
                name: 'code'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you follow the URL in your code, it responds with some JSON saying: "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active".

Comment: Ya but it gives a JSON response. Also tried with http://bitcoincharts.com/t/markets.json . Ends with the Same error.

Comment: Might want to see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359224/parsererror-after-jquery-ajax-request-with-jsonp-content-type/5359239#5359239

Answer (score 0):

Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyJsonPStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

```
requires: [
    'MyApp.model.MyModel'
],

config: {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
    storeId: 'MyJsonPStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        /*url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json',*/Url not valid
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'errors'
        }
    }
}
```

});

Comment: I also tried with url:'http://bitcoincharts.com/t/markets.json' but error remains the same