# Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin ERROR

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

My application was working  fine last week. This is the ajax request:

```
              $.ajax(
              {
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?",
                data: {
                   origin: start.replace(/ /g,'+'),
                   destination: end.replace(/ /g,'+'),
                   waypoints: 'optimize:' + false + '|' + waypts.join('|').replace(/ /g, '+'),
                   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                   sensor: false           
                      },
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function(){alert("done");},
                  error: function(){ alert("error");} 
                });
```

today it is throwing this error :

```
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Now Is searched it over. I tried adding `jsonp` in my ajax request. Which generated this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : json:2
```

I don't understand what is going wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [parsererror after jQuery.ajax request with jsonp content type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359224/parsererror-after-jquery-ajax-request-with-jsonp-content-type)

Comment: I think you need to use the JavaScript API now instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26198407/3069376