# Can I call the google maps directions API from a web page (as opposed to a server)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am a long time programmer (C, Python, FORTRAN), but this is my first foray into javascript and anything web, so I am learning on the fly.

So, the main question up front:  Can I use the google maps directions API from  a script section of a simple web page on my laptop, or does it need to be called from a server?

I have an API key and I have successfully used parts of the API that are called as functions (Map, Geometry).  I am trying to use the google maps directions API, which as I understand it, you must use via a URL and an HTTP GET.  Here is a sample URL that my code has constructed:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=45.0491174%2C-93.46037330000001&destination=45.48282401917292%2C-93.46037330000001&key="my key"

If I paste that URL into the address bar, it works.  I get a document back with the directions info.  If I execute it from inside a script section on a simple web page I am building, the response I get is:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I did some searching, both in stackoverflow and elsewhere on the web and I came across this:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Per that page, I checked to make sure that withCredentials was supported and then I set withCredentials to true.  This did not alter the outcome.  Obviously, the API works, so I am now wondering if I have to do this from a web server and not from a simple web page to get around the cross-domain limitations. I am hoping to avoid having to set up a server since this is a one-off for my own personal use, but maybe I dont have a choice?

As an aside, does anyone have any insight into why the directions API is called via a URL rather than as a javascript function like many of the others?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)?

Comment: Based on my reading and testing, you have to have a pay/premium account to use the service.  That is what I tried first.  If there is a way to use with a free key, I am happy to do that.

Comment: Where did you see that?  Are you planning on using more than the "free" quota?

Comment: I will try and find the web reference where I saw that and post it here.  I did get an error return from an attempt that had an error that I interpreted  to confirm it.  I will try and reproduce that and post it as well.  As to the quota, that should not be an issue.  Worst case test runs will require 40 queries total.  A worst case full blown run, which I only need to do once (correctly) will have a worst case of 900 queries and a more likely half that or less.

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Legs) it says: duration_in_traffic indicates the total duration of this leg, taking into account current traffic conditions. The duration_in_traffic is returned only if all of the following are true:

The request includes a valid Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID.  However, I now see that I could get just the duration not taking into account traffic with a free token.  That will probably be sufficient for my needs.

Comment: @geocodezip provided me a workaround, which is much appreciated, but I would still be interested in understanding the javascript limitations in a web page.  I asked specifically about the google maps API, but I would like to understand the general answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript better use the [Web -> Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions). This helped me solve this issue without a server.

The problem is that your [Web Services -> Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) unlike e.g. the [Web Services -> Geolocations API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), does not provide JS XSS functionalities like server side `access-control-allow-origin: *` response headers or JSONP functionality. Maybe this is even a bug of Google because it seems very strange to me that one "Web Services" API server does allow JS XSS and another not.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26198407/3069376

Answer (score -1):

To answer the main question, Yes. You can definitely use the GoogleMap Directions API inside your web page. To get you started quick and easy, follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) . Then,

1. Click on the JAVASCRIPT + HTML version, copy the whole code and paste it into a text editor and save it as an html file.
2. Start your own local server (like node.js). Dont forget to obtain a Browser API key and set your HTTP refferer (example `http://localhost:4567`) in Google Developer Console or you will get errors.
3. Run your html file on your local server (example `http://localhost:4567/myprojfolder/samplewebfile.html`) .

You can do this with all Google Maps JavaScript API samples. If you're curious about setting a node.js server, there are plenty of resources online.

Comment: This was helpful.  I did not realize there were different classes of credentials.  However, in your step 2, you say start a server, which is at the heart of my question (though perhaps I did not phrase it clearly).  What I have been doing so far is just opening the .html file in my browser, no server running on my end.  Based on your directions, it sounds like a server is required?