# How to render JSONP GET response to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, get

I've tried to send GET request to a multiple hosts and to render the response status in separated foe each host.
The code below it works fine for xhttp request but in case of **jsonp** data type *(to avoid of Access-Control-Allow-Headers errors)* I need to use another json type to send the request and can't use the regular function.
In the code below it using ajax request and I didn't manage to use the responseHandler function to render the response status.
Please your help how to correct this code.

```
var hosts = ['http://www.bla.com:8082/bla','http://www.bla2.com:8082/bla','http://www.bla3.com:8082/bla', 'http://www.bla4.com:8082/bla']; //Added


var ledTypes = {
    green: "<img id='logo' src='green.png' height='30' width='30'>",
    red: "<img id='logo' src='red.png' height='30' width='30'>",
    yellow: "<img id='logo' src='yellow.png' height='30' width='30'>"
};

var hostIndx = 0;

function collectionChecking() {

    for  (hostIndx < hosts.length; hostIndx++;) {
           $.ajax({
                url: hosts[hostIndx],
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonpCallback: "_stdout",
                cache: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                timeout: 10000,
               success: handleLedResponse(data, textStatus, jqXHR, hostIndx) { alert(data); },
               error: handleLedResponse(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, hostIndx) { alert(errorThrown); }
            })
    }
}

function handleLedResponse(textStatus, hostIndx) {
    var curSpan = document.getElementById('col_host_' + hostIndx);
    if (textStatus === 200 || textStatus === 204) {
        curSpan.innerHTML = ledTypes.green;
    } else if (textStatus === 500 || textStatus === 404) {
        curSpan.innerHTML = ledTypes.red;
    } else if (textStatus === 300 || textStatus === 301 || textStatus === 302) {
        curSpan.innerHTML = ledTypes.yellow;
    }
```

**The trigger to run this script:**

```
 <li><a href="#tabs-2" onclick="collectionChecking()">Services status</a></li>
```

The response are rendered to the index.html as well

Comment: Are you trying to collect data from ``Web sockets (ws) Server`` using ajax?

Comment: No.. I've changed the example in the code now..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

`for(; hostIndx < hosts.length; hostIndx++) {`
 First issue was in for loop syntax. Your loop didn't work. try `console.log(hostIndx)` in your loop.

```
   function collectionChecking() {

    for(; hostIndx < hosts.length; hostIndx++) {

           $.ajax({
                url: hosts[hostIndx],
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonpCallback: "_stdout",
                cache: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                timeout: 10000,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { handleLedResponse(textStatus, hostIndx) },
                  error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { handleLedResponse(textStatus, hostIndx); }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably it will work, but It receives a parser errors so maybe that is the reason the status does't render..
Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5359239/1640577. This is your issue. right ?